# how to load huge number of files in mysql using java?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

> I have about 200 millions of text files in a folder and i need to load them in mysql. I can not use LOAD LOCAL DATA command since my text files are in raw format and i need to parse them first. I am using Java for this. Issue is that I am able to process only 1500 files at a time (takes 5 to 10 minutes for processing) and after that I get Java heap source error, I have tried -xms arguments but still the problem is same. 
>   Is there a way to parse all files and load them in mysql in reasonable time. Thanks.

Comment: 1500 in parallel? Do you really need to do as much at same time?

Comment: I don't think that you can expect a helpful answer with the amount of information you are providing - the problem seems far too general. Also I guess that your file processing either has an issue (e.g. a memory leak) or that you should simply process less files at once.

Comment: I suggest you look at a proper EIP/ETL Tool to start doing this. I would recommend Apache Camel as I am loading huge text files with it and very quickly. However I agree with previous comment this is way too little information to give you and answer.

Comment: @Jan, Namphibian, Please let me know what else information i should provide.

Comment: @Alex, 1500 not in parallel, it's just when i read files and load them in mysql, it process only 1500 files. after that there is java heap source error.

Comment: For now what I am doing is that I divided all files in several chunks of folders and accessing one folder at a time but then it will take whole day to load those files.